# Java 7 handshake_failure bouncy castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, handshake

I have a handshake_failure problem towards an api service, the problem is created by a set of incompatible ciphers, i'm using java 1.7 with spring and maven.
the api server testing from ssllab to tls1.2 has as ciphers TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_25386_CBC
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
I can't find a solution, reading I found bouncy castel, can it be a valid solution? how can i use it? Thank

Comment: Java (1.)7 supports some of the ciphersuites you listed (assuming 25386 is just a typo) though not all; I suggest getting a trace (sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` or wireshark tcpdump etc) to confirm what your system is sending. Are you sure it isn't the _protocol_? Oracle j7 _implements_ up to TLS1.2 but (except some paid versions well above 7u80) client by default offers only 1.0, which many servers today won't accept; that can be fixed in code (which you didn't show). In recent Bouncy you can install the bctls jar and configure its provider instead of (or before) 'standard' JSSE.

Comment: Yes I am sure that it is not the protocol I force the use of tls 1.2 as already done in other services, but with this one using tls 1.3 and tls 1.2 with the ciphers I have listed I just can't make calls.